# Unable to invoke no-args constructor for retrofit2.Call MVVM Coroutines Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I want to use coroutines in my project only when I use coroutines I get the error :Unable to invoke no-args constructor. I don't know why it's given this error. I am also new to coroutines.

here is my apiclient class:

```
class ApiClient {

    val retro = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
```

Here is my endpoint class:

```
@GET("v2/venues/search")
  suspend   fun get(
        @Query("near") city: String,
        @Query("limit") limit: String = Constants.limit,
        @Query("radius") radius: String = Constants.radius,
        @Query("client_id") id: String = Constants.clientId,
        @Query("client_secret") secret: String = Constants.clientSecret,
        @Query("v") date: String
    ): Call<VenuesMainResponse>
```

my Repository class:

```
class VenuesRepository() {

    private val _data: MutableLiveData<VenuesMainResponse?> = MutableLiveData(null)
    val data: LiveData<VenuesMainResponse?> get() = _data


   suspend fun fetch(city: String, date: String)  {

        val retrofit = ApiClient()
        val api = retrofit.retro.create(VenuesEndpoint::class.java)

        api.get(
            city = city,
            date = date
        ).enqueue(object : Callback<VenuesMainResponse>{

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<VenuesMainResponse>, response: Response<VenuesMainResponse>) {

                val res = response.body()
                if (response.code() == 200 && res != null) {

                    _data.value = res

                } else {

                    _data.value = null
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<VenuesMainResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                _data.value = null
            }
        })
    }

}
```

my ViewModel class:

```
class VenueViewModel( ) : ViewModel() {

    private val repository = VenuesRepository()

    fun getData(city: String, date: String): LiveData<VenuesMainResponse?> {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                repository.fetch(city, date)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("Hallo", "Exception: " + e.message)
            }
        }
        return repository.data
    }

}
```

part of activity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private lateinit var venuesViewModel: VenueViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: HomeAdapter
    private var searchData: List<Venue>? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.main_search)
        venuesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[VenueViewModel::class.java]
        venuesViewModel.getData(
            city = "",
            date = ""
        ).observe(this, Observer {

            it?.let { res ->
                initAdapter()
                rv_home.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                adapter.setData(it.response.venues)
                searchData = it.response.venues
                println(it.response.venues)
            }
        })
```

this is my VenuesMainResponse data class

```
data class VenuesMainResponse(
    val response: VenuesResponse
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `no-args constructor` warning should be related to your `VenuesMainResponse`, is it a `data class`? You should add the code for it as well and the complete `Log details`

Also, with `Coroutines` you should the change return value of the `get()` from `Call<VenuesMainResponse>` to `VenuesMainResponse`. You can then use a `try-catch` block to get the value instead of using `enqueue` on the `Call`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67599330/13343177) answer for knowing about it and feel free to ask if this doesn't solve the issue yet :)

**UPDATE**

Ok so I just noticed that it seems that you are trying to use the `foursquare` API. I recently helped out someone on `StackOverFlow` with the `foursquare` API so I kinda recognize those `Query` parameters and the `Venue` response in the code you provided above.

I guided the person on how to fetch the `Venues` from the `Response` using the `MVVM` architecture as well. You can find the complete code for getting the response after the `UPDATE` block in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68384451/13343177).

This answer by me has code with detailed explanation for `ViewModel`, `Repository`, `MainActivity`, and all the `Model` classes that you will need for fetching `Venues` from the `foursquare` API.

Let me know if you are unable to understand it, I'll help you out! :)

**RE: UPDATE**

So here is the change that will allow you to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68384451/13343177) code with `Coroutines` as well.

> Repository.kt

```
class Repository {

    private val _data: MutableLiveData<mainResponse?> = MutableLiveData(null)
    val data: LiveData<mainResponse?> get() = _data

    suspend fun fetch(longlat: String, date: String) {

        val retrofit = Retro()
        val api = retrofit.retro.create(api::class.java)
   
        try {

            val response = api.get(
                longLat = longlat,
                date = date
            )
            _data.value = response
        } catch (e: Exception) {

            _data.value = null
        }
    }
}
```

> ViewModel.kt

```
class ViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val repository = Repository()

    val data: LiveData<mainResponse?> = repository.data

    fun getData(longLat: String, date: String) {

        viewModelScope.launch {

            repository.fetch(longLat, date)
        }
    }
}
```

> api.kt

```
interface api {

    @GET("v2/venues/search")
    suspend fun get(
        @Query("ll") longLat: String,
        @Query("client_id") id: String = Const.clientId,
        @Query("client_secret") secret: String = Const.clientSecret,
        @Query("v") date: String
    ): mainResponse
}
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<ViewModel>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewModel.getData(
        longLat = "40.7,-74",
        date = "20210718" // date format is: YYYYMMDD
    )

    viewModel.data
        .observe(this, Observer {

            it?.let { res ->

                res.response.venues.forEach { venue ->

                    val name = venue.name

                    Log.d("name ",name)
                }
            }
        })    

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mehul, how should I change my code in the classes?

Comment: I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Yess Mehul I saw that answer but I want to use Coroutines with that code, I think now its fetching on the main thread

Comment: Ok I'm updating the code for using it with `Coroutines`. Do tell if it fixed it for you.

Comment: yeah, nice to hear that :)

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue with compose desktop. Using the java 11, the code worked fine, but after I upgraded to java 17, I get this no-args error